# Batch File Path Weirdness

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I've made this batch script to delete some things from local app data and the redirected user folders.

This whole thing works quite well apart from one little snag....

```
   set share=\\SERVER\d$\tsprofiles\%USERNAME%.V2\AppData\Roaming
   ECHO Deleting..... %share%
   net use Y: %share% 
   cd /D Y:\
   del * /F /S /Q
   del * /F /Q
   net use Y: /DELETE /YES
```

For some reason the path that the var share creates navigates to the UNC path in explorer that I'm trying to map to Drive Y: yet when using:

```
net use Y: %share%
```

No dice. I'm sure its not a permissions issue as I am running this from a domain admin account and an admin command prompt....

Comment: whats that single double quote doing there?

Comment: huh weird. Thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately it doesn't have the first " in my code. I'll update the post

Comment: `net use Y: "%share%"`? Some error message? Add `pause` to see if any.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT set share=\\SERVER\tsprofiles$\%USERNAME%.V2\AppData\Roaming is what it at now (still a hidden share unfortunately). Still no dice "The system cannot find the file specified.... JosefZ also I put the var in " " marks. Still no joy. Also I've tried both of the paths and stuck them into powershell with a Test-Path returning true on both of the different UNC paths...

Comment: can someone look into this? Thanks https://superuser.com/questions/1415868/batch-scripting-how-to-code-a-unc-path-and-set-it-on-a-directory-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason the path that the var share creates navigates to the UNC path in explorer that I'm trying to map to Drive Y: yet when using:

I'm not sure what you mean by "navigates to the UNC path".  Do you mean it changes to that directory instead of creating a share?

Also, I'm not sure why you need to map the UNC share to delete its contents.  Couldn't you just use the UNC path directly like below?

```
set share=\\SERVER\d$\tsprofiles\%USERNAME%.V2\AppData\Roaming
ECHO Deleting..... %share%
del "%share%\*" /F /S /Q
del "%share%\*" /F /Q
```

Also, I noticed your example is indented.  Is that snippet from a condition/loop block enclosed in parenthesis? For example `IF EXIST "\\SERVER\d$" ( <your script lines here> )`.

If the script is nested in a parenthesis block, you should use delayed expansion on the `share` variable using exclamation points instead of percentage symbols like this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF EXIST "\\SERVER\d$" (
   set share=\\SERVER\d$\tsprofiles\%USERNAME%.V2\AppData\Roaming
   ECHO Deleting..... "!share!"
   net use Y: "!share!"
   cd /D Y:\
   del * /F /S /Q
   del * /F /Q
   net use Y: /DELETE /YES
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Otherwise, the share variable will always be the same value it was when the parenthesis block was entered into instead of the value you set it to.

And, as has already been stated in the comments, you need to quote the share in case `%USERNAME%` has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being like me over complicating the hell out of it all. So based on @David Woodward's suggestion I've done a bit of a re-design

> Also, I'm not sure why you need to map the UNC share to delete its
>   contents. Couldn't you just use the UNC path directly like below?
>
> ```
> set share=\\SERVER\d$\tsprofiles\%USERNAME%.V2\AppData\Roaming
> ECHO Deleting..... %share%
> del "%share%\*" /F /S /Q
> del "%share%\*" /F /Q
> ```

So what I ended up with is a much more streamlined script that is a whole lot better to read and a whole lot faster. Thank you all so much!

```
SET dir=%~dp0
SET userfolder="\\SERVER\userfolders$\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming"
SET tsprofiles="\\SERVER\TSPROFILES$\%USERNAME%.V2\AppData\Roaming"
SET localdata="C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp"
SET inetcache="C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache"
REM Start of script
@ECHO OFF
ECHO [(===============================================================)]
ECHO ^|^|                                                               ^|^|
ECHO ^|^|  Remove un-neccecary files from %USERNAME% on %COMPUTERNAME%  ^|^|
ECHO ^|^|                                                               ^|^|
ECHO [(===============================================================)]
ECHO Deleting.... %inetcache%
del "%inetcache%\*" /F /S /Q > null
del "%inetcache%\*" /F /Q > null
ECHO Deleting.... %localdata%
del "%localdata%\*" /F /S /Q > null
del "%localdata%\*" /F /Q > null
ECHO Deleting.... Using UNC path %USERFOLDER%
del "%userfolder%\*" /F /S /Q > null
del "%userfolder%\*" /F /Q > null
ECHO Deleting.... Using UNC path %tsprofiles%
del "%tsprofiles%\*" /F /S /Q > null
del "%tsprofiles%\*" /F /Q > null
ECHO Return to working DIR
cd /D %dir%
```

I've posted it above if anyone finds it useful

Comment: Why do you `cd /D %dir%`? Your script never does a `CD` to anywhere else.

Comment: It was mostly because running it from a Shortcut that launches it as Administrator does some weird things when referencing the next login script from within the batch. For some reason it will depending on how it feels at the time either go back to the right place or mysteriously find itself back to System32